# Performance of static referencing vs local referencing

Tags: java, static

I have a utility class that provides a set of algorithms (like supporting repetitive tasks when I parse input from different sources with the same format) and have made all the methods in this class static, added with a private constructor, so the methods can be used without needing to instantiate the class.

I was wondering now whether this is good practise performance-wise? Or is it better to remove all the static tags from the methods and instantiate classes more locally for when I need the methods?

Comment: `static` methods are faster as they are simpler.  However, you should consider what is the best design primarily and a more OOP approach may be better esp if you have state i.e. try to minimise static state as much as possible.